# composer require which will be the opposite operation?

Tags: php, composer-php

I have an environment that work several people, I'm a guest so I must adapt to this environment. 
I can't do composer update
I can do composer require

but how can I remove a specific package without update all
I mean which will be the opposite operation of composer require?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the composer documentation.

```
php composer.phar remove vendor/package vendor/package2
```

Source: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#remove

Comment: and this will be not update all? this only affect to a single package?

Comment: I did this... It running for several minutes and nothing happen, It doesn't end yet I mean doesn't start ... how long does it takes?

Comment: It depends a lot on system memory allowances, as it will also be looking for other packages installed as dependencies of said package which aren't required by other vendors. It also depends a lot on your system privileges, you mention you are a guest. Are you this is an operation you should be performing? It seems slightly strange you can do a require but not an update.

Answer (score 5):

Try with `composer remove vendor/yourpackage`

Answer (score -3):

You can delete a certain package and then run composer install, it will automatically remove the unregistered package on composer.json

i hope this answer help you :)

Comment: No it won't. Composer install runs from the lock file.

Comment: Do not encourage people to manually edit `composer.json` when there are adequate commands available.

Comment: I don't see any issue with manually editing composer.json directly, it gives far more precision over what you want and what versions. Plus theres a lot more to a composer.json files than just which packages you wish to include. You have your namespace/psr(0,4) setup, project name and dev vs prod dependencies plus much more. However the OP asks for a way to remove an item without using the require command within CLI.

Comment: Thanks for his advice, this will help me to be better